# How to create a label with the number from variable in asm

Tags: c, assembly, jit, brainfuck

I want to write JIT compiler which will be based on the Brainfuck interpreter. The whole code of the program will be written in C. I created all instructions except loops. I have an idea to calculate offsets of matching loop brackets, but to do this I need to create the local labels in asm with the unique numbers. But each number in the name of the label should be a value from the variable. This is what I want to do in C:

```
void jit(struct bf_state *state, char *source)
{
    size_t number_of_brackets = 0;

    while (source[state->source_ptr] != '\0')
    {
        switch (source[state->source_ptr])
        { 
            case '[': 
            {
                number_of_brackets++;
                __asm__ ("start_of_the_loop<number_of_brackets>:\n\t"
                         "pushl <number_of_brackets>\n\t"
                         "cmpb $0, (%%rax)\n\t"
                         "je <end_of_the_loop<number_of_brackets>>"
                         : 
                         : "a" (state->memory_segment), "d" (number_of_brackets));
            }
            break;
            case ']': 
            {
                __asm__ ("end_of_the_loop<number_of_brackets>:\n\t"
                         "popl %%edx\n\t"
                         "cmpb $0, (%%rax)\n\t"
                         "jne <start_of_the_loop<number_of_brackets>>"
                         : 
                         : "a" (state->memory_segment), "d" (number_of_brackets));
            }
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Can I create the labels with the number from the variable in asm? This will help me a lot. I will be grateful for the answer. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't safely jump from one asm statement to another.  You can use [`asm goto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#index-asm-goto-labels) to tell the compiler you might jump to a C label instead of falling through, though.

But there's a fatal flaw with your whole idea for mixing asm and C to use the call-stack as a stack data structure: **you can't leave `rsp` modified at the end of an asm statement**.  You'll break compiler-generated code that references stack memory relative to RSP, because `-fomit-frame-pointer` is on by default (except with `-O0`).  And even if not, the compiler assumes it knows where RSP is pointing even in functions that do use a frame pointer.

BTW, `pushl` is illegal in 64-bit code, only 16 and 64-bit operand-sizes for `push` are available.

Also, if you're going to `pop` into a register, you should use an output operand for that constraint, not an input.

---

There's also another fatal flaw: **inline-asm can't JIT**.  All the asm has to be there at build time.  Just like C++ templates, `start_of_the_loop<number_of_brackets>` can't work if `number_of_brackets` isn't an assemble-time constant.

Comment: So when I want to JIT something only way to do this is to place opcodes into the writeable and executable memory and execute this?

Comment: @KamilSzpakowski: yup.  There are libraries that can help with this, like LLVM.  You can feed it LLVM-IR (an asm-like language), and it can produce optimized machine code.  But GNU C inline asm isn't going to help you.